# Displaying an umbraco field from a .net usercontrol

Tags: .net, umbraco

I cannot read an umbraco page field from a .net user control (front end) .ascx file

I have tried this

```
<umbraco:item runat="server" field="fieldName"></umbraco:item>
```

which is what I would normally use within a masterpage

because i am trying to read this from within a usercontrol is the xpath different or do I need to use umbraco.library...

Comment: turns out the umbraco item was inside an asp panel with visibility set to false, I have moved umbraco item to a jquery variable then reading it via jquery and injecting it where i need it within the panel.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would use the Umbraco api in the code behind of the user control to load the node and set the desired properties to the value of a control within the user control. An example is given in the [Umbraco docs](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/uQuery/Content/Nodes) showing how to query a node and get a property's value:

```
Node currentNode = uQuery.GetCurrentNode();

string heading = currentNode.GetProperty<string>("heading");
```

This gets the value of the property that has the alias of "heading".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Node currentNode = Node.GetCurrent();
String fieldValue = currentNode.GetProperty("fieldName").Value ;
```